How to extract just the open port numbers from nmap
Right now my aim is to scan a single IP and get only the open ports printed in a single line separated by commas.
The code below does that but it injects % at the end.
The goal is to extract port numbers in a single line as output without the last 2 characters (the last comma and % sign)
sudo nmap -vv -sS 10.129.208.16 -oG  - | awk -v OFS=':' '
/open/ {
  for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
    split($i,a,"/");
    if (a[2]=="open") {printf a[1]","}
  }
}'

Output:
21,22,53,80,139,443,445,%

Required output:
21,22,53,80,139,443,445


please update the question with the output from your nmap call so we can see the format of the data

i found the solution
ports=$(sudo nmap   -sS 10.129.229.137 | grep -E '^[0-9]+' | cut -d '/' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/,$//)  sudo nmap -sC -sV -p $ports 10.129.229.137

By using printf
{printf a[1]","}

like so you are risking malfunction if a[1] will hold template with 1 or more places to fill, consider that
echo "%s/%s" | awk '{split($0,a,"/");printf a[1]","}'

will result in fatal error due to not enough values for fill places. More robust solution is to provide template yourself
echo "120/60" | awk '{split($0,a,"/");printf("%s,",a[1])}'  # outputs 120,
echo "%s/%s" | awk '{split($0,a,"/");printf("%s,",a[1])}'  # outputs %s,


goal is to achieve port number

to do so you might add to condition check if a[1] is integer, together with fix of above described issue gives code
sudo nmap -vv -sS 10.129.208.16 -oG  - | awk -v OFS=':' '
/open/ {
  for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
    split($i,a,"/");
    if (a[2]=="open"&&a[1]~/^[0-9]+$/) {printf("%s,",a[1])}
  }
}'

Explanation: only printf if a[2] is open AND (&&) a[1] has one-or-more (+) digits ([0-9]) spanning from begin (^) to end ($) i.e. a[1] consist solely from digits and has at least 1 digit.
Disclaimer: I am unable to test due to lack of output of leading command.
If you want to know more about printf usage read Using printf Statements for Fancier Printing

First, install python-yq (possibly in a venv), which also installs a fun wrapper called xq.
pip install --user yq

Maybe with a venv?
sauer@host:~$ python -m venv ~/dev/yq
sauer@host:~$ . ~/dev/yq/bin/activate
(yq) sauer@host:~$ pip install yq

(if you use a venv, you can just source the activate script to use this again in the future, then just run deactivate to exit the venv environment after)
Then, use your jq skillz to select what you want from the XML output, and combine the output using paste in serial mode (-s) with comma delimiters (-d,).
sudo nmap -vv -sS 192.168.0.0 -oX - | xq -r '
  .nmaprun.host
  | .ports.port[]
  | select( .state."@state" == "open" )
  | ."@portid"
'  | paste -s -d,

That gives me this when 192.168.0.0. is replaced with an actual machine listening on several ports: 22,25,53,80,88,111,139,389,443,445,514,631,1080,2049,3000,3128,3306,3493,5432,8001,8080,8443,9090,9101,10000
I put a pipe between host and ports because host becomes a list and thus needs host[] with multiple hosts.

ports=$(sudo nmap   -sS 10.129.229.137 | grep -E '^[0-9]+' | cut -d '/' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/,$//)
sudo nmap -sC -sV -p $ports 10.129.229.137
